# Excel Userform pass variable to Range

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a worksheet which I have set to let the user open a userform if it contains the text "[View Data]". My thought was that I can send the current active cell row into a variable and then apply it when retrieving data. This works partially, I can get the active cell row, but I am unable to apply it within the Range. The error occurs in Read_Data:

```
Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range
```

I would appreciate some help in getting to a solution

---

This is what I have for Modules -> Module1:

```
Public activeCellNow As Integer
```

This is what I have in Microsoft Excel Objects -> Sheet1:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    With Target
        If 1 = .Cells.Count Then
        activeCellNow = ActiveCell.row
        If .Value = "[View Data]" Then Details.Show
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

This is what I have in Forms -> Details

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    MsgBox (activeCellNow)
    Call Read_Data
End Sub
```

The message box shows the correct row number

```
Private Sub Read_Data()

    txt_manager.Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & (activeCellNow)).Value
    
End Sub
```

Comment: It works for me, where exactly does the error occur?  Is it the line in the `Read_Data` method?

Comment: @Skin I've edited my post to make it clear. It is in Read_Data

Comment: If you get error 9 on that specific line, it means that you don't have a sheet named "Sheet1"  in the Active Workbook.

Comment: @FunThomas - thanks that was exactly the issue.

Comment: @Skin after your comment, I tried it in a blank project instead of my existing one and it worked absolutely fine.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved issue. I tried it on a new project and the syntax I wrote worked fine. Thanks to @Skin and @FunThomas for the tips :)